# Error: Expression<String?> is not convertible to String

Tags: swift, sqlite.swift

My code is:

```
func getTimeStamps( tablename : String) -> String {
    let time_stamps = db["time_stamps"]
    let t_tabelle = Expression<String?>["tabelle"]
    let t_time_stamp = Expression<String?>["TIME_StAMP"]
    let query = time_stamps.filter(like(tablename, t_tabelle))

    return query[t_time_stamp]
}
```

But I get an error on conversion:

> `Expression<String?> is not convertible to String`

How can I return a String?

Thanks 
Hauke

Comment: What is Expression ? Can you post more code please ?

Answer (score 0):

The error refers to the fact that your function signature for `getTimeStamps`, `String -> String`, has return type `String`, but the value you're returning, `query[t_time_stamp]`, is an `Expression<String?>`.

`Query` structures can be subscripted with `Expression`s to return a namespaced version of the expression:

```
let id = Expression<Int64>("id") // literally: "id"
let users = db["users"]
let users_id = users[id]         // literally: "users"."id"
```

In your case, subscripting `query` with `t_time_stamp` is merely returning a new, namespaced version of the `t_time_stamp` expression (in your version, `"time_stamps"."TIME_StAMP"`). This is helpful for [disambiguation](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#column-namespacing), but unlikely your intent.

It's tough to tell from the code provided *exactly* what you want to return from the function, but it looks like you want to execute the query in order to extract a value. `Row` structures, once fetched, can be subscripted with expressions to retrieve the underlying value.

If you're looking to retrieve a single row, try the following:

```
if let row = time_stamps.filter(like(tablename, t_tabelle)).first {
    return row[t_time_stamp]
}
```

---

Your function, however, still returns `String`, not `String?`. If it's ever possible for your query to return zero rows or for any of the rows it *does* return to have a `NULL` timestamp column, you need to handle your optionals accordingly.

If, however, a `NULL` timestamp would indicate a programming error/bug, you should update `String?` to `String` accordingly:

```
let t_time_stamp = Expression<String>["TIME_StAMP"]
// ...
return query.first![t_time_stamp]
```

Please note that **the above will crash** if you're mishandling the potential for optional values.